# Frequent DNS failures requiring connection reset

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dns

Staying in a shared accommodation where I have no access to the wifi router in question so I can't change any settings there.
Linux Mint 19.2 laptop, every half an hour or so DNS fails (browser says 'looking up hostname') and the only fix for me is to disconnect and reconnect from/to the access point.

Anything I can do locally? Had Windows 10 on this very laptop until a fortnight ago and didn't face this problem there.

Comment: When in this state, can you ping the gateway? It may be more than just DNS failure.

Comment: Yeah, I can ping the gateway.